# Mismatch between MeasureString on Windows and Ubuntu in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I use `System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString` for string measuring but it returns different results for the same parameters on Windows and Ubuntu computer. On Ubuntu, I get bigger value than on Windows. At first, it didn't even work on Ubuntu and I had to install these packages `libc6-dev, libgdiplus` and its dependencies.

Getting different values is quite a problem for me because the exact value has consequences in the application.

I use .NET Core 2.1, System.Drawing.Common v4.5.0

Can I somehow achieve the same values on both platforms?

Comment: Did you really expect them to be the same? Graphical operations on two unrelated operating systems? That's why you.measure things, to try to make them act in a similar fashion

Comment: Actually, I expected them to be the same. So you say it is a valid behavior and my app should not be dependent on the exact number?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to see different numbers between two Windows systems that have different graphics cards and different aspect ratio screens.  User settings can change the results of MeasureString

Comment: `System.Drawing` is considered part of Windows Compatibility Pack for .NET Core, so currently Microsoft only supports using it on Windows officially. Yes, you might be able to run it on other platforms via `libgdiplus` the behavior is unpredictable. Like @Flydog57 mentioned, what you observed can be intentional, and corefx repo should be the right place to discuss, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues

Comment: What makes you say that System.Drawing.Common is not supported by Microsoft on non-Windows platforms? Do you have a link to documentation or an official statement for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to craft a small program which allows others to reproduce your problem, you should be able to file a bug against libgdiplus. There's quite some work being done to improve the compatibility between libgdiplus and GDI+, so there are some chances that this may get fixed.

The repository for libgdiplus is at https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error with .Net 6 and I fixed it with installing microsoft fonts with the following commands

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Click **tab** to choose ok to accept license

```
sudo fc-cache -f
```

and it was fixed